# Wie sagt man »up to« in der Mathematik?

Tags: phrase-request, mathematics

Der Begriff *up to* in der Mathematik ist ziemlich wichtig, so wichtig, dass er einen [eigenen Wikipedia-Artikel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to) hat. Leider gibt es kein deutsches Äquivalent (es gibt 7 andere Sprachen!).

Wie drückt man dieses Konzept auf Deutsch aus? Wie sagt man etwa die Beispiele von der Wikipedia-Seite? Hier sind einige:

- > There are seven reflecting tetrominos, up to rotations.
- > There are 92 unique solutions up to permutations of the queens.
- > There are two different groups of order 4 up to isomorphism.

Comment: Die Tatsache, dass ein Begriff einen eigenen Wikipedia-Artikel hat, sagt nicht aus, dass der Begriff generell wichtig ist. Das sagt nur aus, dass es mindestens eine Person gibt, die den Begriff für so wichtig hielt, dass sie ihm einen Artikel auf Wikipedia gewidmet hat. Ich halte z.B. den englischen mathematischen Begriff »greater« für wichtiger als »up to«, trotzdem hat »greater« keinen eigenen Artikel (»größer« übrigens auch nicht).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das stimmt so nicht wirklich: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_%28mathematics%29), [2](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vergleich_%28Zahlen%29).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die deutsche Entsprechung ist *bis auf* (mit Akkusativ): *bis auf Drehung*, *bis auf Permutation*, *bis auf Isomorphie*.

Comment: Für Nicht-Mathematiker ware mir das zu knapp; Alternativen sind *ohne Berücksichtigung von*, *abgesehen von* jeweils mit Plural, der mir auch bei *bis auf* passender erscheint.

Comment: @guidot: Nach meinem Verständnis ist das _X_ in _bis auf X_ eine Kategorie bzw. ein Prozeß, so daß der Plural nicht sinnvoll ist. Google-Suchen ergeben für _bis auf Drehung(en)_ und _bis auf Permutation(en)_ jeweils ein Verhältnis von etwa zwei Dritteln zu einem Drittel zugunsten des Singulars und bei _bis auf Isomorphie(n)_ – mit Abstand am häufigsten verwendet von den dreien – sogar eine 98%-Mehrheit für den Singular. (_Bis auf Isomorphismus/Isomorphismen_ kommt auch vor, aber ebenfalls vernachlässigbar gegenüber _bis auf Isomorphie_.)

Comment: @guidot: Ich kann die Verwendung von "bis auf" mit vorwiegend Singular in der angegebenen knappen Form in der Mathematik bestätigen.

Comment: Bei *Drehung* hätte ich vielleicht den Plural benutzt, bei *Isomorphie* sicher nicht, bei *Permutation* bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher.

Comment: @guidot mach doch daraus noch ne Alternativantwort?

Comment: To me, the most satisfying is „bis auf Isomorphie“, because „Isomorphie“ is the equivalence relation given by „Isorphismus“, a distinction not easily made in English.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt da zwei Möglichkeiten: *bis auf*, was schon oben erwähnt wird, und, wenn man mehr den informellen Mathematikerslang verwenden will: *modulo*.